# Why sequence-identity not working in SQL server sequences?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sequence, hibernate-mapping

Why sequence-identity not working in SQL server sequences?

```
@GenericGenerator( name = "sequence",
            strategy = "sequence-identity",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                            name = "sequence",
                            value = "SEQ_PARTNER_TIMETABLE_ID"
                    )

        })
```

Comment: can you edit your post to include what is "not working"?

Comment: Please try to give what exactly the error you facing. Please give the details  in an understandable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

in SQL Server create a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [schema_name . ]sequence_name   
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     NO CYCLE
    ;
```

then call this sequence in your entity's id

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "users_seq_gen", sequenceName = "sequence_name")
```